# How can I optimize this code that uses “itertools.product” on 3 repeated dimensions? The execution times out

Tags: python, optimization

the purpose of this code is to return the number of times that you can split seq into three where the sum of integers is equal for all 3 parts. This code works for test cases but times out on execution. Is there anyway to optimize the for loop so that its much quicker?

```py
from itertools import product

def three_split(seq):
    answer=0
    q=0
    w=0
    e=0
    for i,j,k in product(range(1,len(seq)), repeat=3):
        if (i+j+k==len(seq)):
            q=sum(seq[:i])
            w=sum(seq[i:i+j])
            if q==w:
                e=sum(seq[i+j:])
                if w==e:
                    answer+=1
    
    return(answer)
```

Comment: The solution likely involves moving to something more problem specific: the product is doing a seq * seq * seq, for a problem in O(n^3) time. For non-trivial value of n, this is expected to timeout (as it approaches ridiculous execution times), even with an ‘optimized’ C.

Comment: That said, depending on seq, a simple change like “l = len(seq)” or “seq = list(seq)” may pay off well, even without changing the bounds.. adding additional details to the question, such as calling code, may be beneficial.

Comment: Bit too short for an answer, but in terms of your algorithm, you can very improve to O(n^2) by iterating over pairs of `i, j`, because you know `k = len(seq) - (i + j)`. I believe there exists a O(n * log n) solution by using partial prefix sums and a binary search. There are probably also other (possibly better) solutions. You can only get so far by optimising your implementation before you need to turn to your algorithm.

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations` instead of `itertools.product` since you don't want repeats or overlaps

Comment: Are you trying to check if a sequence can be split into three consecutive equal parts (this is what is implemented now), or find all possible ways to split into three equal parts, even if elements of each part won't be consecutive in `seq`?

Answer (score 1):

You need an algorithm much better than **O(N^3)**.
First, the problem statement trivially implies that the sum of each subsequence *must* be `target = sum(seq) / 3`  Start by computing this **target sum**.
From here, the problem is "trivial"

1. Find each prefix -- each position `i` for which `sum(seq[:i]) == target`.  This is **O(N^2)**, but a running sum will keep it to **O(N)**.
2. Similarly, find each *suffix* -- each position `j` for which `sum(seq[:j:]) == target`.  This is also **O(N^2)**, can be held to **O(N)**.
3. Your solutions consist of all pairs (i, j) form the about sets for which i<=j.

Code:

```
target == sum(seq) // 3   # You might need to check that this sum is divisible by 3.
i_vals = [i for i in range(len(seq)) if sum(seq[:i]) == target]
j_vals = [j for j in range(len(seq)) if sum(seq[j:]) == target]

solution = [(i, j) for i in i_vals for j in j_vals if i <= j]
```

Comment: Isn't your code for steps 1 and 2 O(N^2) because `sum` is typically O(N), and the code is executing that check O(N) times. This could be fixed by accumulating the prefix and suffix sum as the sequence is iterated, which is what I think you were describing.

Comment: Ahhh, good point; you're right.  The accumulation is a bother, but I think I can bring it into range with the walrus operator.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations` will generate all unique indices without repeats and will produce far fewer values. You also need to only generate two values, one for each index to split on as this will produce three lists.

Something like the following should work

```
from itertools import combinations

def three_split(seq):
    answer = 0
    for i, j in combinations(range(1, len(seq)), r=2):
        if sum(seq[:i]) == sum(seq[i:j]) == sum(seq[j:]):
            answer += 1
    return answer
```